# Jsoup ArrayList Creation

Tags: java, arraylist, web-scraping, jsoup

Let's say I have a site that is ordered like this:

```
<div id = "main">
  <div class = "cat"
   <div class = "cat_top"
   <h3>Math Class</h3>
 </div>
 <ul>
  <li class = "student_male">
   <span class = "name">Buddy</span>
   <span class = "age">22</span>
  </li>
  <li class = "student_female">
   <span class = "name">Kristy</span>
   <span class = "age">24</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

So far, I've been doing this:

```
ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList();
Element main = doc1.select("div#main").first();
for(Element e : main.select("div.cat")){
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

I want to add all the text to an ArrayList, but I can't figure out how to separate it so that it is something like this:

```
Cat1:
Name: Buddy
Age: 22
Name: Kristy
Age: 24
Cat2:
Name: Student
Age:23
Name: Student
Age: 25
```

I'm just not sure how to traverse these categories so that it is formatted in my array list so that it is readable instead of being one long list. Maybe I need multiple ArrayLists, I'm not sure as I'm kind of new to Java.

Comment: Use map where you will have `<key,pair>` you cant store the Items.

Comment: Some of your tags are not closed (with `>` or with `</tag>`) which kind of prevents us from seeing structure you want to describe. Only indicator of their nesting is indentation but it doesn't match your HTML. You should correct it to not confuse (1) people willing to help you, (2) people with potentially similar problems which will read your question in the future.